# when debugging code i get the same error: fputc.c:no such file or directory, but i don't have such file in my code

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct BirdHome{
  int area;
  int height;
  int feederquantity;
  char hasNest[2];
};
struct Bird{
  char isRinged[2];
  char nameSpecies[50];
  int birdAgeMonths;
  struct BirdHome hom;
  char gender[2];
};



int main(){
  char * filename="bird.dat";
  /*the 3 subjects of this structure*/
  struct Bird sparrow={"T","sparrow",4,{30,20,2,"F"},"M"};
  struct Bird crane={"F","crane",10,{200,100,4,"T"},"F"};
  struct Bird griffin={"T","griffin",60,{500,80,7,"T"},"M"};
  /*call of the functions "save" and "load"*/
  save("bird.dat",&sparrow);
  load("bird.dat");
  return 0;
}



int save(char * filename, struct Bird *bird){
  int i;
  FILE * fp1;
  char * d;
  int size=sizeof(struct Bird);
  d=(char*)bird;
  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    fputc(*d,fp1);
    d++;
  }
  fclose(fp1);
  return 0;
}
int load(char*filename){
  int i;
  FILE *fp1;
  char* c;
  int size=sizeof(struct Bird);
  struct Bird *ptr=(struct Bird*)malloc(size);
  c=(char*)ptr;
  while((i=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF){
    *c=i;
    c++;
  }
  fclose(fp1);
  printf("%s\n",ptr->isRinged);
  free(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Welp,the problem is when i try to call the function "save", the program stops with an error: fputc.c:no such file or directory, while i don't have any file with this name. i see that the problem here is inside a cycle in a "save function" but simply changing the name of the counter of bytes doesn't work. I've tried to even mix them that caused the same error but with the file lowlevellock.h

Comment: Don't you need to `fp1 = fopen(filename, "w")` before you can write to `fp1`? The same (but with `"r"` mode) for `load`: You must associate a filoe with the file pointer. At the moment, your file pointers are uninitialized.

Comment: yes, the guy in the answers made me see this mistake. i redesigned my code but still the error didn't dissappear

Comment: @Anim233: Don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. If you have a different question, write a different question.

Comment: Better yet, listen to your compiler warnings before posting another question. You don't do what "the guy in the answer" does. Instead you pass a string ( `char *`) to `fputc`, wher a `FILE *` is expected. Please have another look at the chapter on file handles in your C book. This is basic stuff.

Comment: OT: it is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used in the program.  Suggest removing all those include statements except for `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. does not include header files those contents are not used
4. uses appropriate horizontal and vertical spacing (for readability)
5. documents why each header file is included
6. consistently indents the code, using 4 spaces per indent level
7. properly checks for (and handles) I/O errors
8. uses appropriate prototypes for called functions

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fopen(), fclose(), perror(), fputc(), fgetc()
#include <stdlib.h>  // malloc(), free(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE


struct BirdHome
{
    int  area;
    int  height;
    int  feederquantity;
    char hasNest[2];
};

struct Bird
{
    char  isRinged[2];
    char  nameSpecies[50];
    int   birdAgeMonths;
    struct BirdHome hom;
    char gender[2];
};


// prototypes
void save(char * filename, struct Bird *bird);
void load(char*filename);


int main( void )
{
    char * filename="bird.dat";

    /*the 3 subjects of this structure*/
    struct Bird sparrow={"T","sparrow",4,{30,20,2,"F"},"M"};
    //struct Bird crane={"F","crane",10,{200,100,4,"T"},"F"};
    //struct Bird griffin={"T","griffin",60,{500,80,7,"T"},"M"};

    /*call of the functions "save" and "load"*/
    save( filename ,&sparrow );
    load( filename );
    return 0;
}


void save( char * filename, struct Bird *bird )
{
    FILE * fp1 = fopen( filename, "w" );
    if( ! fp1 )
    {
        perror( "fopen to write file failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    char *d = (char*)bird;

    for( size_t i=0; i<sizeof(struct Bird); i++ )
    {
        fputc( d[i], fp1 );
    }
    fclose(fp1);
}


void load(char* filename )
{
    FILE *fp1 = fopen( filename, "r" );
    if( ! fp1 )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read file failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    struct Bird *ptr = malloc( sizeof(struct Bird) );
    if( ! ptr )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    int i;  
    char *c = (char*)ptr;
    while( ( i = fgetc( fp1 ) ) != EOF )
    {
        *c= (char)i;
        c++;
    }

    fclose(fp1);
    printf( "%s\n", ptr->isRinged );
    free( ptr );
}
```

a run of the proposed code results in:

```
T
```

Answer (score 1):

`fputc.c` is a part of the standard library implementation on your computer. Since you haven't built the standard library yourself, you probably don't have this file. This is normal.

If you get an error in a function you didn't write, use your debugger to walk the stack up to the first function you did write. You will see a call to some library function that is external to your code, perhaps `fgets`. You need to use the debugger to analyze arguments you pass to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Wild pointer! `FILE * fp1;` is used but never initialized.

Need:

```
fp1 = fopen(filename, "w");
if (!fp1) {
    perror(filename);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you for seeing my mistake. i've redesigned my code, and this problem dissapperared. but another one appeared